# Deleting rows based on values in other rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I was looking for a way to drop rows from my dataframe based on conditions to be checked with values in another row.

Here is my dataframe:

```
product product_id  account_status
prod-A  100         active
prod-A  100         cancelled
prod-A  300         active
prod-A  400         cancelled
```

If a row with account_status='active' exists for a product & and product_id combination, then retain this row and delete other rows.

The desired output is:

```
product product_id  account_status
prod-A  100         active
prod-A  300         active
prod-A  400         cancelled
```

I saw the solution mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223638/pandas-delete-rows-based-on-other-rows) but couldn't replicate it for strings.

Please suggest.

Comment: Is it possible account_status will have more than just "active" and "cancelled" statuses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For more general solution removing only another `account_status` values per groups if exist at least one `active` value there:

```
print (df)
  product  product_id account_status
0  prod-A         100         active
1  prod-A         100      cancelled <- necessary remove
2  prod-A         300         active
3  prod-A         400      cancelled
4  prod-A         500         active
5  prod-A         500         active
6  prod-A         600      cancelled
7  prod-A         600      cancelled

s = df['account_status'].eq('active')
g = df.assign(A=s).groupby(['product','product_id'])['A']
mask = ~g.transform('any') | g.transform('all') | s
df = df[mask]
print (df)
  product  product_id account_status
0  prod-A         100         active
2  prod-A         300         active
3  prod-A         400      cancelled
4  prod-A         500         active
5  prod-A         500         active
6  prod-A         600      cancelled
7  prod-A         600      cancelled
```

Also working nice with multiple categories:

```
print (df)
  product  product_id account_status
0  prod-A         100         active
1  prod-A         100      cancelled <- necessary remove
2  prod-A         100        pending <- necessary remove
3  prod-A         300         active
4  prod-A         300        pending <- necessary remove
5  prod-A         400      cancelled
6  prod-A         500         active
7  prod-A         500         active
8  prod-A         600        pending
9  prod-A         600      cancelled

s = df['account_status'].eq('active')
g = df.assign(A=s).groupby(['product','product_id'])['A']
mask = ~g.transform('any') | g.transform('all') | s
df = df[mask]
print (df)
  product  product_id account_status
0  prod-A         100         active
3  prod-A         300         active
5  prod-A         400      cancelled
6  prod-A         500         active
7  prod-A         500         active
8  prod-A         600        pending
9  prod-A         600      cancelled
```

Answer (score 4):

IMO, `groupby` is not necessary (I say this because you have tagged your question accordingly), you can use `sort_values` and `drop_duplicates`, taking advantage of the fact that "active" < "cancelled", lexicographically:

```
(df.sort_values(['account_status'])
   .drop_duplicates(['product', 'product_id'])
   .sort_index())

  product  product_id account_status
0  prod-A         100         active
2  prod-A         300         active
3  prod-A         400      cancelled
```

---

In the spirit of being consistent the other answers, you may want to take a look at `groupby`-based solution involving `duplicated` and masking.

```
df
  product  product_id account_status
0  prod-A         100         active
1  prod-A         100      cancelled
2  prod-A         100        pending
3  prod-A         300         active
4  prod-A         300        pending
5  prod-A         400      cancelled
6  prod-A         500         active
7  prod-A         500         active
8  prod-A         600        pending
9  prod-A         600      cancelled


m1 = (df.assign(m=df.account_status.eq('active'))
        .groupby(['product', 'product_id'])['m']
        .transform('any'))
m2 = df.duplicated(['product', 'product_id'])

df[~(m1 & m2)]

  product  product_id account_status
0  prod-A         100         active
3  prod-A         300         active
5  prod-A         400      cancelled
6  prod-A         500         active
8  prod-A         600        pending
9  prod-A         600      cancelled
```

Like the other solution, this also generalises "nicely" to multiple categories, and will remove rows corresponding to other statuses only in groups where "active" is also present.

Comment: quite a smart solution to this very question (y)

Comment: agreed not a generic solution, but for this very question it will work good

Comment: @Shrey I''ve added a generic solution.