# Remove rows from Pandas dependent on multiple values in other rows

Tags: python, pandas, filter

I would like to remove all rows which are already contained within a previous start:end range.

example df:

```
   length  qstart  qend  sstart  send
0    5464       1  5459       1  5460
1     400    3619  4015    4654  4258
2     396    4261  4653    4012  3619
3     203    1210  1411    1086  1287
4     203    5486  5689    5490  5693
5     100    5500  5600    5310  5410
```

ie, by looking at qstart:qend, I would like to remove all rows /below/ this row which are contained within the range qstart:qend (1:5459), and apply this behavior to all remaining rows as well.

Ive tried making masks and merging dataframes together similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39223638/pandas-delete-rows-based-on-other-rows), but I could not scrape together something that worked. I also looked at df.shift() solutions, but this only can look at fixed intervals between rows and is not dynamic as far as I can tell. I can solve this problem looping and treating it like python, but this is a slow method and I would like something more Pandas-y.

So, as mentioned above, this works but is slow and does not scale well. It is also implemented for only qstart:qend pairs, and not for the other sstart:send pairs (though in this example the output would be the same).

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'length': {0: 5464, 1: 400, 2: 396, 3: 203, 4: 203, 5:100},
              'qstart': {0: 1, 1: 3619, 2: 4261, 3: 1210, 4: 5486, 5:5500},
              'qend': {0: 5459, 1: 4015, 2: 4653, 3: 1411, 4: 5689, 5:5600},
              'sstart': {0: 1, 1: 4654, 2: 4012, 3: 1086, 4: 5490, 5:5310},
              'send': {0: 5460, 1: 4258, 2: 3619, 3: 1287, 4: 5693, 5:5410}})


removeRows=[]
for i in range(len(df.index)-1):
    for j in range(i,len(df.index)):
        if df.iloc[j]['qstart']>df.iloc[i]['qstart']:
            if df.iloc[j]['qend']<df.iloc[i]['qend']:
                removeRows.append(j)
print(df[~df.index.isin(removeRows)])
```

```
   length  qstart  qend  sstart  send
0    5464       1  5459       1  5460
4     203    5486  5689    5490  5693
```

#### Expected

input (df is sorted by 'length'):

```
   length  qstart  qend  sstart  send
0    5464       1  5459       1  5460
1     400    3619  4015    4654  4258
2     396    4261  4653    4012  3619
3     203    1210  1411    1086  1287
4     203    5486  5689    5490  5693
5     100    5500  5600    5310  5410
```

output:

```
   length  qstart  qend  sstart  send
0    5464       1  5459       1  5460
4     203    5486  5689    5490  5693
```

Comment: instead of trying to remove the unwanted elements. you should make a new list which contains only the needed items... sometimes its best to not filter by elimination.

Comment: why did row 5 get removed?

Comment: Good that you provided sample data!!, However it doesnt match your display: 6459 instead of 5459 for qend in the first row.

Comment: row 5 is eliminated because of row 4. @Andrew good catch thank you! I fixed it -- I manually tweaked the data for a better example

Comment: @mmcguffi what is the actual size of your dataframe?

Comment: @Ben I have ~10,000s -> ~100,000s of dataframes such as these, ranging from len==1 to len>100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution 1

This produces the expected result, but the execution time is comparable or slower than your two `for` loops.

```
df['remove'] = False            
for i in df.index:
    df['remove'].loc[(~df['remove']) & (df['qstart'] > df.loc[i, 'qstart']) & (df['qend'] < df.loc[i, 'qend'])] = True
ddf = df.loc[~df['remove']]
```

I first add a column called `'remove'`, each element set to `False` which keeps track of the rows to be removed.
The loop on the index changes to `True` the elements of `'remove'` column according to your condition. It is done for each row.
Then you can create a new dataframe `ddf` by selecting all the rows where `'remove'` is `False`.

#### Solution 2

A similar but faster solution is to loop over combinations of rows:

```
from itertools import combinations
df['remove'] = False
for i, j in combinations(df.index, 2):
    if not df.loc[j, 'remove']:
        df.loc[j, 'remove'] = df.loc[j, 'qstart'] > df.loc[i, 'qstart'] and df.loc[j, 'qend'] < df.loc[i, 'qend']
ddf = df.loc[~df['remove']])
```

Similar in concept, but here we select each pair once, which speeds up the execution time. Solution 1 `loc` selection check each time the entire dataframe, so there is a lot of useless comparison.
According to my test, this should be faster than the two `for` loops.

For both solution, suppressing the `SettingWithCopyWarning` warning with

```
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
```

improves execution time.

Comment: This unfortunately is much slower than the 2 loops and also does not return the correct dataframe

Comment: I didn't test about time, but the result is correct. `ddf` has rows 0 and 4. I'll see if I can think something faster.

Comment: Ah, yes you are correct I apologize -- I had the wrong dataframe loaded in memory. Speed is still an issue however

Comment: Actually if you suppress the warning it give with (pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None) it speeds this up orders of magnitude, but it is still a tad slower than the loops. +1 for definitely being more pandas-y though!

Comment: @mmcguffi I've edit my answer, check Solution 2. Thanks for the suggestion on suppressing the warning!

Comment: I have found Solution 2 to be the best answer here. Thank you @Valentino!

Comment: If the answer was helpful, please consider to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Other possible solution it`s to iterate through rows using

> df.iterrows()

and implement an if statement to check the desired condition:

```
start = 0
end = 0
for x in df.iterrows(): 
    next_start = x[1]["qstart"]
    next_end = x[1]["qend"]
    if (start < next_start) & (end > next_end):
        df.drop(x[0], inplace = True)
    else:
        start = next_start.copy()
        end = next_end.copy()
```

and then you can sort the dataframe using

```
df.sort_values(by = "length")
```

Comment: This is a bit more "pythonic" than what I was looking for (though, it is a bit more "pandas-onic" than my example). It runs at about the same speed as my 2 loops, but this solution does work

Answer (score 0):

```
i = 0
while i < len(df):
    qstart = df['qstart'].iloc[i]
    qend = df['qend'].iloc[i]
    df = df.query('qstart <= @qstart or qend >= @qend')
    i += 1
```

Comment: This is quick, but it does not return the correct dataframe (only rows "0" and "4" should remain)

Comment: Edited to change the approach

Comment: This actually still fails in some use cases -- I am not quite sure why, but in testing it let through some cases that should have been filtered out